# Why after apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services', it's always show error android.view.InflateException

Tags: android

After I apply plugin `com.google.gms.google-services`, it's always show error:

> android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file: Error inflating class
>   pl.droidsonroids.gif.GifImageView.

I think it's use string and drawable of `build/generated/google_service/debug/values`.

In build.gradle:

```
dependencies {

compile 'pl.droidsonroids.gif:android-gif-drawable:1.1.+'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

In XML:

```
   <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/midori_layout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@id/anchor_line"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|left"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/anchor_line"
            android:orientation="vertical">



            <pl.droidsonroids.gif.GifImageView
                android:id="@+id/image1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:scaleType="centerInside"
                android:src="@drawable/image1" />

        </FrameLayout>
```

If I remove `android:src="@drawable/image1"`, it can work. I don't know why. Please help me.

Comment: Have you added this line on top of your xml  ?  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/package.name

Comment: @devganiya how does that help in this case? Your suggestion/comment has no connection with the stated problem in the question.

Comment: @DevganiyaHitesh I tried add xmlns:app="schemas.android.com/apk/res/package.name, but it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this bug by change

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'
```

By

compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.+'

It can work on Android 4.0 and 5.1